# PlayFramework and MongoDB Auto-Reconfiguration Error

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am having an issue with auto-reconfiguration using Play2 and MongoDB.  Any help would be much appreciated.  I have emailed the error log, compiled application and application.conf to support@cloudfoundry.com..

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, just to be clear, have you bound a MongoDB service to the application?

Comment: Correct.  I created an instance of the mongodb service and bound it during vmc push.

Comment: Anyone out there from CloudFoundry?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response! Is it possible for you to provide a copy of the application either mailed to support@cloudfoundry.com or dropbox?

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for responding.  Is it possible to provide configuration files for the app without source?  Thanks!

Comment: Ground control to CloudFoundry :)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay on this, please do provide the configuration.

Comment: I should also add that I have tried this myself with a Play 2 application and at present, can't get auto configuration to work. I have created a ticket on the Cloud Foundry bug tracking system - https://cloudfoundry.atlassian.net/browse/CF-141

Comment: I have posted it here..  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yh54aoghmu3klg5/IWuwTcWwnq

Comment: Yup, its pretty clear this doesn't work, in the interim you can get details on all the connected services via the environment. See http://show-env.cloudfoundry.com/ for example output (it's a node app).

Answer (score 1):

just to bring this thread up to date;

Please see the comments on the filed ticket at https://cloudfoundry.atlassian.net/browse/CF-141

> We only implemented Play auto-reconfig for Postgres and MySQL. We
>   would like to do auto-config for the additional services like Mongo,
>   but need to find a common pattern for usage in a Play app (one
>   possibility is common property names in application.conf). In the
>   meantime, you can externalize connection props to application.conf and
>   use the CF-provided props that get resolved on app start:
>   mongodb.host=${?cloud.services.mongodb.connection.hostname}
>   mongodb.port=${?cloud.services.mongodb.connection.port}
>   mongodb.db=${?cloud.services.mongodb.connection.db}
>   mongodb.username=${?cloud.services.mongodb.connection.username}
>   mongodb.password=${?cloud.services.mongodb.connection.password}

Comment: Hi,
I have done the following configuration.

db.default.driver=${?cloud.services.mysql.connection.driver}
db.default.url=${?cloud.services.mysql.connection.url}
db.default.password=${?cloud.services.mysql.connection.password}
db.default.username=${?cloud.services.mysql.connection.username}

Its throwing an following error .
  ERR Caused by: Configuration error: Configuration error[dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.]